# Populating array from select query in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsmutablearray

So I'm fairly new to iOS development and I'm having problems with my select function. I made a function that *should* take in a select query and the table name and return an array of results where each array entry is a dictionary with a row of results. Somehow my query for column names is deleting my `columnNames` variable and returning crazy results. I'm just trying to figure out an easy way to store, access, manipulate query results

Here is the function that converts results into array:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)selectQuery:(NSString*)query
                     table:(NSString*)table
{
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray new];

if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSMutableArray *columnNames;
    NSString *tableQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRAGMA table_info('%@')", table];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [tableQuery UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [columnNames addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error preparing table query:");
        NSLog(tableQuery);
    }

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *temp= [NSMutableDictionary new];

            for (int i = 0; i < [columnNames count]; i++)
            {
                [temp setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)] forKey:columnNames[i]];
            }

            if (temp != nil)
            {
                [returnArray addObject:temp];

                temp = nil;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error preparing select statement with query:");
        NSLog(query);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Could not open database");
}
return returnArray;
}
```

and heres the call to it

```
NSMutableArray *queryResults = [dbInstance selectQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT gallons, mileage FROM fillups WHERE carId = \"%d\" ORDER BY date asc",
                                                   carId]
                                            table:@"fillups"];
```

Comment: "Somehow my query for column names is deleting my columnNames variable and returning crazy results" What is your evidence for that? What is _actually_ happening? Describe the facts, not the conclusions you've formed...

Comment: BTW, you don't have to call the `pragma table_info` call if you don't want to. There are SQLite function calls to return the column names from your select statement (e.g. `sqlite3_column_count` to get the number of columns and `sqlite3_column_name` to get the column name). That way, you're automatically retrieving the names of the columns from the SQL statement, rather than from the table definition (and you're saving yourself from having to call the `PRAGMA table_info`).

Comment: matt, that IS what is actually happening as I followed it from the debugger. This is not some crazy conclusion based on arbitrary points that I've formed. Wish there was a down vote for comments.

Comment: Rob, thanks so much for looking into this. All the information you gave me is really helpful. Ill change it right away and let you know how it works :)

Comment: @bia.migueis Also, are all of your columns `TEXT` values? If not, you might want to create the appropriate object type on the basis of `sqlite3_column_type`.

Comment: thanks ill look into that, Right now im just converting everything to text then converting back later on in code :S terrible i know but im getting there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are never instantiating `columnNames`. Thus, your attempt to add column names to that array will not succeed. To remedy this, when you declare it, you want to instantiate the mutable array object, too:

```
NSMutableArray *columnNames = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Unrelated to this problem, when you're done retrieving the column names, before you prepare your second statement, don't forget to release the memory associated with the first prepared statement:

```
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Finally, when you're done retrieving the second prepared SQL statement, rather than calling `sqlite3_reset`, you want to call `sqlite3_finalize` again for that second prepared statement. The `sqlite3_reset` is used to reset a statement when you want to bind new values to `?` placeholders in a statement, which is not applicable here, so no `sqlite3_reset` is needed. But if you don't call `sqlite3_finalize`, you're not releasing the memory associated with the prepared statement.

---

By the way, if you wanted to dynamically retrieve the column names and column types (without having to do `PRAGMA table_info`), you could do something like:

```
int rc;

if ((rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"select failed %d: %s", rc, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(statement);

id value;

while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        NSString *columnName   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)];
        switch (sqlite3_column_type(statement, i)) {
            case SQLITE_NULL:
                value = [NSNull null];
                break;
            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)];
                break;
            case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                value = @(sqlite3_column_int64(statement, i));
                break;
            case SQLITE_FLOAT:
                value = @(sqlite3_column_double(statement, i));
                break;
            case SQLITE_BLOB:
            {
                NSInteger length  = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, i);
                const void *bytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, i);
                value = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:length];
                break;
            }
            default:
                NSLog(@"unknown column type");
                value = [NSNull null];
                break;
        }
        dictionary[columnName] = value;
    }

    [returnArray addObject:dictionary];
}

if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) {
    NSLog(@"error returning results %d %s", rc, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Comment: Perfect, this answer and the comment on the OP really helped. Its working like i wanted now. Thanks :)

Comment: @bia.migueis I've updated my answer with code sample showing how you could dynamically determine column names/types without `PRAGMA table_info`.